# Can unauthorized people read the database from the client side in meteorjs?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, client-side, database

I have this messages collection containing several message objects each with an uniques ID. Now user X can only have access to to a message object of ID, lets say, 123456. Now is it possible that user X opens up the developer tools, change the JS file and read the messages from 147852?

Like when the user logs in I check my user collection and get the appropriate ID and assign it to a variable called `msgID`. Then I

```
message = Meteor.Collection('messages').id(msgID);
```

do that to get the messages. Can the user change that message ID to some thing static like 104758 and read the messages he/she didn't permission to?

I'm sorry if this is like a simple question but I'm very new to this Meteor thingy and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a new Meteor project includes the packages `autopublish` and `insecure`, which give each client full read/write access to the database. This might be useful for prototyping, but it's obviously a bad idea for a real application, so you should remove these with `$ meteor remove autopublish insecure`. At this point, clients have no access at all. You'll have to add access back using [publish/subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe) (for read access) and either [allow/deny rules](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) or [methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) (for write access).

See the relevant section in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity).

Publications, allow/deny rules and methods run on the server. A client might mess around with their own version of the Javascript, but that only affects the code running on their client. The code running on the server, or on the other clients, is not affected by this.
To answer your question:

- If you are relying on `autopublish` and `insecure`, and authorising access on the client, then this is not secure, since the user can change their own client's Javascript code to bypass your client-side authorisation.
- If you are not using `autopublish` and `insecure`, and have properly written publications, allow/deny rules and/or methods, then you are fine. The client can only read and write through this interface.

Comment: Since the original js file gets edited, won't the user have the necessary permission to make a write request?

Comment: Your publications, methods and allow/deny rules run on the server. A user can't change the server's code, only their own client's code.

Comment: (Well, you can run methods on the client too, for latency compensation, but that only affects that client's screen; the server's version of the method is authoritative.)